# How to get float value from object in Vector?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, vector

In this method, I want to convert a `Vector` to a `float[][]`, but I get the error that the indices 0,1,2 of the Vector are `objects` and can't be directly converted to `float`.

How can I resolve this problem?

As with `toString()`, I've tried `toFloat()`, but that didnt work either.

```
float[][] vectorToMx(Vector v) {
    float[][] m = new float[3][1];
    m[0][0] = v.get(0);
    m[1][0] = v.get(1);
    m[2][0] = v.get(2);
    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java Vector class is a generic class. If you aren't familiar with generic types, I would recommend you check out the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Anyhow, if you don't specify the generic type of your Vector, like so: `Vector<Float>`, it is considered a raw type, which essentially means a Vector of objects, and not a Vector of floats as you intended.

This would be a fix to your problem:

```
float[][] vectorToMx(Vector<Float> v) {
    float[][] m = new float[3][1];
    m[0][0] = v.get(0);
    m[1][0] = v.get(1);
    m[2][0] = v.get(2);
    return m;
}
```

Comment: (assuming the `Vector` actually contains instances of `Float`)

Comment: Alright at this point im just going to switch my IDE. I tried that exact thing like 5 minutes ago and it still showed as being wrong. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger yes it does.